# Why am I getting more and more ATA bus errors over the time which can be fixed by un- and replugging the HDD caddy?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, ssd, sata

I have an internal SATA connector and a HDD caddy in my Laptop Lenovo IdeaPad Z500-Touch. No matter which HDD (tried 1TB HDD and 2TB HDD) or SSD (Samsung Extreme 256GB) I put in the caddy (I tried two different, one from hddcaddy.com, the other unknown) after some weeks I'm experiencing the first `ATA bus error`s logged to `kern.log` which seem to be recoverable. Within one week the number of occurances is increasing so that the boot is delayed (up to 1 minute) because of hundreds of ATA bus errors. At some point the write errors destroy the `btrfs` filesystem I have to restore from a backup.

As soon as I un- and replug the HDD caddy there're no ATA bus errors for weeks and the scenario starts the same. I've experienced this >3 times now. I don't see any corrosion on the SATA connector and the screws are fixed safely.

I've experienced this with Linux 4.3.0 and 4.3.3, but the way this issue is worked around makes me doubt that it's a software issue.

Comment: *"I don't see any corrosion on the SATA connector"* -- You cannot always see oxidation.  You could try a (chemical) contact cleaner, which I've used to solve many issues (e.g. "weak" battery, noisy audio connections).  Be sure to clean both sides on the connection (laptop and caddy).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cleaned the connectors with [Nigrin contact spray](https://www.nigrin.de/de/produkte/nach/produkt/nigrinkontaktspray) which is not especially for SATA connectors. I didn't work because the issue reappeared after weeks.

Cleaning with 98 % vol. alcohol now works for 24 months.

Comment: Try different SATA port, and try a different cable.  If you have a really long SATA cable try a shorter one.  Also it's possible but very unlikely something weird could be causing interference with the signal, you might try physically relocating it away from any high powered GPU.